# unable to understand why my throw/catch output is not working

Tags: java

I am just learning about try, and catch in Java. Since the second input in one of the expected outputs is a string and not a number an error is expected. It is expecting this output:

Lee 19
Lua 22
Mary 0
Stu 34

The input is:

### Lee 18
Lua 21
Mary Beth 19
Stu 33

So when I try run my code I actually get:

Lee 19
Lua 22
Mary 0
Beth 20
Stu 34

My code:

```
package study3;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class NameAgeChecker {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      String inputName;
      int age = 0;
      
      
      
      inputName = scnr.next();
      while (!inputName.equals("-1")) {
         // FIXME: The following line will throw an InputMismatchException.
         //        Insert a try/catch statement to catch the exception.
          try {age = scnr.nextInt();
         
         }
         
         catch (InputMismatchException expct) {
             
             age = -1; 
              
         }
         System.out.println(inputName + " " + (age + 1));
         
         inputName = scnr.next();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception occurs, you need to "eat" the wrong input, so add `scnr.next()` in your `catch` block.

```
            try {age = scnr.nextInt();
            }

            catch (InputMismatchException expct) {
                age = -1;
                scnr.next();
            }
```

Comment: Actually I ate it twice. So I used scnr.next() two times and it works now!